# Passar DataTime javascript para Controller ASP.NET MVC por Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou com problema para passar data do javascript para o Controller via ajax..

Model:

```
public class ModelA{
   ....
   [Required]
   DataType(DataType.Date)]
   DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
   Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
   public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
   ....
}
```

No campo do html está `'type=date'`

E o JavaScript com todas as tentativas que fiz até o momento...

```
var postForm = {
            ...
            'DataNascimento' : $('#DataNascimento').val() //original
            //'DataNascimento': '2011-04-02 17:15:45',    //tentativa
            //'DataNascimento': new Date().toISOString()  //tentativa
            //'DataNascimento': '02-04-2011'              //tentativa
            //'DataNascimento': '02/04/2011'              //tentativa
            ...
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Portal/Register",
            type: "post",
            data: postForm,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Dados enviados...");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Erro");
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Em todos os casos o controller recebe na propriedade `ModelA.DataNascimento = null`, nas outras propriedades tudo funciona..

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo??

Obrigado!!

[Edit]

Codigo HTML do campo

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Data de Nascimento é obrigatório." id="DataNascimento" name="DataNascimento" type="date" value="" />
```

Comment: Tem como mostrar o html desse campo ? Para que possa analizar o que está acontecendo, aparentemente esse campo não possui id por isso está retornando null

Comment: Oi, obrigado @KirmayrTomaz pelo retorno, tem id sim, inclusive se jogar no console `$('#DataNascimento').val()` ele mostra a saída exemplo:
"1992-02-01"

Comment: Testei aqui, se der submit no form a data vai com o valor certo.. mas preciso fazer via ajax..

Comment: Cara olhando esse trecho de código o js tá certo, não sei o que é =/

Comment: Fiz de todos jeitos que achei, aqui no stack pt e no stack.. atualizei até ojquery kk.. não sei mais o que fazer heheh, mas obrigado pela ajuda @KirmayrTomaz

Comment: Passe a data como texto mesmo, depois converte para data dentro da controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O jeito que funcionou, depois de muito bater a cabeça foi o seguinte:

Criar os Binders customizados para DateTime (C#)

```
Global.asax 

protected void Application_Start()
{
    ....
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DatetimeBinder());
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DatetimeBinder());
    ....
}
```

Classe DatetimeBinder()

```
public class DatetimeBinder : IModelBinder
{

    public DatetimeBinder() { }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(DateTime) || bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            String data = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue;
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            bool okData= DateTime.TryParse(data, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
            if (okData)
            {
                return dt;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(bindingContext.ModelType) != null)
                    return null;

                return new DateTime();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Não sei se é o jeito "certo", mas foi o único jeito que funcionou para mim